# EV Wall Charger with built-in metering?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

**Background**

I plan to purchase a new electric vehicle in the coming months (a Tesla Model 3).
My parking garage in my apartment building offers electric vehicle charging (unlimited charging for an extra $50 per month).

However, as I'd probably want to get them to install another wall adaptor near my spot (rather than move my spot to one that already has a charger) I thought I might suggest options that would be more fair. $50 per month seems steep with light use, while with a Tesla and heavy use, I could probably draw enough power to make their eyes water when the power bill arrives, so much that they would likely jack up the rates.  So my thinking is to negotiate an arrangement where I simply pay for my share of the electricity.

My ideal solution would be to find a system that could measure usage for particular vehicles charged at that charging station.  While I am out at work, they might charge another EV vehicle so if I just got them to put a meter on the wall adapter to pay my share of the electricity, I might end up paying for someone else's charging.

**Question**

Are there (consumer grade) charging systems (wall adapters) that will track usage?  The perfect one would be one that doesn't need a RFID card or code to activate, but just picks up the VIN number or whatever from the vehicle when it is plugged in.  The parking garage has WiFi so in theory there could be a charger that does this and uploads the statistics to the cloud so one could get a statement at the end of the month, when it is time to pay for the parking spot.

Comment: I am going to say good luck on getting the apartment to agree to that. I am sure the charging station had an installation fee and a price tag and might even require maintenance. So the costs they bare is not just electricity. You are looking for a commercial type unit (tracking, billing etc..) but want it as consumer grade .. I am thinking you will not find it. at .15 cent per KW you are looking at 333 KW of power that is about 900 - 1000 miles per month, at .12 still 1200 miles per month. 1Kw/3Miles. $50 probably a deal for some.

Comment: I agree with @Ken.  Also the apartment isn’t going to want two plans, it’s harder to administer.  Consider also that the existing chargers were probably paid for and installed by the utility, and the apt complex doesn’t pay in the traditional manner for metered electricity for the existing chargers.  (It may or may not be metered power, if it is metered the rate is likely not the residential or small commercial rate).  A few years ago utilities received tax advantages for placing vehicle charging stations for public use.

Comment: And the cost of running conduit and copper to your personal, random parking spot?  This could get very expensive quickly.  For what they would have to charge to recoup the costs, you'd be begging for $50 a month.  Oh, and this is not about Home Improvement at all.

Comment: They may have been more clever than you think, e.g. a separate meter for this load with a different rate that relies on off-peak charging. Some such rates can be *rather low*.  They surely must know someone who buys an electric car will charge it everyday.

Comment: actually, i think you can pull up those stats on your car or online, once you get the car.

Answer (score 2):

### In short, yes

There are at least two consumer-oriented EVSE (Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment) brands that include utility-grade consumption monitoring. PG&E, my utility, actually had a pilot program (which I was a part of) for submetering EV charging. Instead of installing a separate meter, these reported the consumption over time to the utility directly so charging could be billed at a separate rate.

I don't remember all of the options (and I don't want to make this a shopping list), but I have a ChargePoint Home. The app provides consumption data. Similarly, JuiceBox has a more portable solution, which only requires an appropriate receptacle (typically a NEMA 14-50). You'd need a J1772 to Tesla adapter in both cases, but the ChargePoint Home would be a more permanent solution vs. the JuiceBox which is inherently portable.

### Is this worth it, probably not

As many others have said, good luck getting your apartment manaement to agree. They'll need to pull permits for a new 40-60A circuit, have the work done, *and* access the EVSE's data. Given that you don't exactly have much bargaining power, I doubt they'll want to negotiate at all.

Economically speaking, $50/mo. translates to about 400kWh at my utility's EV charging rate. This might be a slightly generous assumption if they allow you to charge at any time because the rate I assumed is only for off-peak hours. Peak hours are much more expensive. Without any Time-of-Use, it'd still work out to 250kWh with my utility.

Your mileage may vary (literally), but I expect you'll likely average 300Wh/mi consumption, which means 250kWh will get you ~833mi and 400kWh will get you ~1333mi. If you drive the average of 1000mi/mo. (which is only about 30mi/day...), then you'd be right on track to pay quite fairly for your charging anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is (or at least, there used to be) a company called "Charge Point" whose business is installing EV charging stations in commercial parking facilities.  Their charging stations can be set up for unlimited use, or for pay-per-use.  I don't know if that means it meters the electricity, or just the time, or just counts the number of times it's been plugged in.

https://www.chargepoint.com/